# How to get Spinner selected item value to string?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have 5 Spinners. In order to make it summary to this.

This is Spinner in xml

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/text_interested"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:entries="@array/interestedarrays"
            android:prompt="@string/interestedprompt" />
```

This is Spinner in Java

```
submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
interested.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(
                                AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int i, long l) {
                            interesting = interested.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(
                                AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                        }
                    });
    }
});
```

Explanation here:

The page got a button. This button will read the data from spinner when pressed. I checked the output with this

```
System.out.println(interested.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
```

It gave me nothing not even null.

How to retrieve the value and to string it?

Comment: I am sure, you want selected item from a spinner whenever user clicks on a button

Comment: Set the setOnItemSelectedListener outside onClick of your button and inside Onclick method use this interested.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: thanks, my mistake was put the listener inside button listener that why no respond

Comment: welcome :) explore api demos ... u can get better examples there

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Try this:

```
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Like this you can get value for different Spinners.

Answer (score 34):

```
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**OR**

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: But how to get item 0?!

Answer (score 14):

You can get the selected item from Spinner by using,

```
interested.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

Get the selected item with Kotlin:

```
spinner.selectedItem.toString()
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
 final Spinner cardStatusSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.text_interested);
    String cardStatusString;
    cardStatusSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            cardStatusString = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

 final Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    saveBtn .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("Selected cardStatusString : " + cardStatusString ); //this will print the result
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

If your Spinner was populated by SQLite cursor, then the solution is:

```
Spinner mySpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspin);
mySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {  
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           SQLiteCursor item = (SQLiteCursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
           String value = String.valueOf(item.getString(0));
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The option is:" + value , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }
```

PS: In `item.getString(0)` -> 0 is the index of column on cursor that you want to get.

Comment: Works great. How do you use "value" outside the onItemSelected member?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the suggested,

```
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

You can do,

```
String Text = String.valueOf(mySpinner.getSelectedItem());
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the latest language for Android Development is Kotlin. Here is, how we do it in Kotlin using Anonymous object.

```
spinnerName?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
       println("Nothing Selected")
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
       val selectedString = yourList[position]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the selected item of the spinner when button is clicked..

Try [getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29):

```
spinner.getSelectedItem()
```

Answer (score 3):

When you choose any value from spinner, then you get selected value,

```
interested.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is :-

```
String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

you can refer the docs here : [Spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sp1 = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
```

Answer (score 1):

By implementing the SpinnerAdapter for your adapter object i use `interested.getItem(i).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    spinnerType = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.account_type);
    spinnerType.setPrompt("Select Type");

    spinnerType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TypeItem clickedItem = (TypeItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String TypeName = clickedItem.getTypeName();
            Toast.makeText(AddAccount.this, TypeName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```