# Transfer data from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to transfer the value of a spinner component in the first activity to an sqlite query in the second activity. going the value throught a Spinner.

First Activity - Filtro_Activity

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Filtro_Activity extends Activity implements      AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filtro_);

    //referencia a Spinner
    //Spinner coligada;

    //final TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //final TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    //final Spinner pday = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final Spinner spcoligada = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.coligada);
    final Spinner spfilial = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.filial);
    final Spinner splestoque = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.lestoque);
    final Spinner spgprodutos = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gprodutos);
    final Spinner spsubprodutos = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.subproduto);
    final Spinner spclprodutos = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.clprodutos);



    //spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adaptercoligada=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.coligada, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spcoligada.setAdapter(adaptercoligada);

    ArrayAdapter adapterfilial=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.filial, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spfilial.setAdapter(adapterfilial);

    ArrayAdapter adapterlestoque=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lestoque, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    splestoque.setAdapter(adapterlestoque);

    ArrayAdapter adaptergprodutos=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gprodutos, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spgprodutos.setAdapter(adaptergprodutos);

    ArrayAdapter adaptersubprodutos=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subproduto, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spsubprodutos.setAdapter(adaptersubprodutos);

    ArrayAdapter adapterclprodutos=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.clprodutos, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spclprodutos.setAdapter(adapterclprodutos);

    Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);


    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //chamada para a nova Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Filtro_Activity.this, ListUsersActivity1.class);
            intent.putExtra("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());
            intent.putExtra("filial", spfilial.getSelectedItem().toString());
            intent.putExtra("lestoque", splestoque.getSelectedItem().toString());
            intent.putExtra("gprodutos", spgprodutos.getSelectedItem().toString());
            intent.putExtra("subprodutos", spsubprodutos.getSelectedItem().toString());
            intent.putExtra("clprodutos", spclprodutos.getSelectedItem().toString());

            //intent.putExtra("nomePessoa", nome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("sobrenomePessoa", sobrenome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("day", pday.getSelectedItem().toString());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

And the other activity is :

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class BD extends Activity {





private SQLiteDatabase bd;

public BD(Context context) {
    BDCore auxBd = new BDCore(context);
    bd = auxBd.getWritableDatabase();
}



public List<Produtos> buscar2() {

    List<Produtos> list = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","item", "coligada","filial"};
    //String whereclausula = "coligada = 'issue'";

    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from produtos2 ", null);
    //Cursor cursor = bd.query("produtos", colunas,null, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {

            Produtos p = new Produtos();
            p.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            p.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            p.setColigada(cursor.getString(2));
            p.setFilial(cursor.getString(3));
            list.add(p);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return (list);
 }
```

As you can see, the second activity has a db.query which I would like to modify with the spinner values from the first activity. Is this possible and what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: You can find similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331854/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-value-to-string

Comment: You can create a public static variable in Second activity and assign the value of spinner item by ActivityName.variablename = ItemSelected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: I 'ill read the " How do I pass... " ,

Comment: arshadkazmi i'll try too , thanks.

Comment: did you try to use Preference @Thiago Emanoel

Comment: no , but i can try. can u give me a example ?

Comment: Could u give more details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just on your BD Class you have to get Value from intent which You pass from first Activity like this

And Main thing is that you pass value in intent to other Activity Not BD so you cant get it in that Activity

replace This line in fitro_activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,BD.class);intent.putExtra("coligada","Your Spinner selected Value");startActivity(intent);
```

In your BD Class On Create write this

```
Intent i = getIntent(); String spn1 = i.getString("coligada");
```

whatever Value you set in putextra of fitroActivity with key of "coligada" you get it in sp1 string.you can check it using print on Toast or Log

Comment: Yes , i think that is this the problem , because my class like , insert , update , view are inside BD.class.

i really dont undestand how to make this works

Comment: Could u explain friend ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use the where clause in your code by selecting the value of coligada ?

Edit answer

in your **Filtro_Activity**

edit your ok button like this

```
Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //chamada para a nova Activity

        Intent intent = new Intent(Filtro_Activity.this, BD.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

in your **BD class/activity** inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState); after setContentView put this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String coligada = extras.getString("coligada");
List<Produtos> list = buscar2(coligada);
```

the coligada string pass to this function like this

```
public List<Produtos> buscar2(String coligada) {

List<Produtos> list = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","item", "coligada","filial"};
//String whereclausula = "coligada = 'issue'";

Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from produtos2 where coligada = ? ", new String[] {coligada});
//Cursor cursor = bd.query("produtos", colunas,null, null, null, null,null);
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {

        Produtos p = new Produtos();
        p.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        p.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
        p.setColigada(cursor.getString(2));
        p.setFilial(cursor.getString(3));
        list.add(p);

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close()
return (list);
}
```

**Updated Answer check below start to this line**

update your **BD Class** like the code below

```
public class BD {

    private SQLiteDatabase bd;
    private String coligada;

    public BD(Context context, String coligada) {
        BDCore auxBd = new BDCore(context);
        this.bd = auxBd.getWritableDatabase();
        this.coligada = coligada;
    }

    public static BD newInstance(Context context, String coligada){
        return new BD(context, coligada);
    }

public List<Produtos> buscar2() {

    List<Produtos> list = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","item", "coligada","filial"};
//String whereclausula = "coligada = 'issue'";

    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from produtos2 where coligada = ? ", new String[] {coligada});
//Cursor cursor = bd.query("produtos", colunas,null, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {

            Produtos p = new Produtos();
            p.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            p.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            p.setColigada(cursor.getString(2));
            p.setFilial(cursor.getString(3));
            list.add(p);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close()
    return (list);
}

}
```

in your **Filtro_Activity**

edit your ok button like this

```
Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //chamada para a nova Activity

        Intent intent = new Intent(Filtro_Activity.this, ListUsersActivity1.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

inside your **onCreate** from the **ListUserActivity1.class** put this code after setContentView();

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String coligada = extras.getString("coligada");
List<Produtos> list = BD.newInstance(getApplicationContext(), coligada).buscar2();
```

Hope this helps you now.

Comment: yes , like " select * from produtos2 where coligada = 'this is the item selected from spinner "

Comment: Just look at my edited answer hope that answer will help you.

Comment: Hey Lester , i think that i'll work ... but , my BD.class dont have " Oncreate " . i 'ill post the full BD.class code friend.

Comment: How many activity do you have ? And list it all .

I think **Filtro_Activity** and **BD** is the activity you're talking ?

Comment: Okay , i'll list all.  

one moment friend.

Comment: Okay , posted all class.

Comment: from what activity do you want to pass a data ? 

do like this 

**activity_name1** to **activity_name2**

Comment: i want choose a item from spinner at "Filtro_Activitty" , 
and the item that a choose go to "BD.class " at code " Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from produtos2 where coligada =" +**this i wanna be the item selected from spinner**, null); " .

after this , i'll be displayed the itens , the activity that show the itens are " ListUserActivity1 "

Comment: Oh so don't extend Activity to your BD class.

Comment: Okay lester , i 'ill try now my friend.

Comment: Check the updated code above **Updated Answer check below start to this line** start below this line

Comment: I made the changes , but , now at " NewUserActivity " is giving the error . 

' Error:(64, 11) error: constructor BD in class BD cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String
found: NewUserActivity
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length '

where have ' BD bd = new BD(this); " the ('this') is red .

Comment: in your NewUserActivity onCreate() put this code

`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String coligada = extras.getString("coligada");
List<Produtos> list = BD.newInstance(getApplicationContext(), coligada).buscar2();
setListAdapter(new ProdutosAdapter(this, list));`

make sure that you never miss any word.

Comment: yes , lets make this code run , so .. i made the changes , i 'll update "NewUserActivity" code to you see , but keeping showing error : "Error:(37, 3) error: cannot find symbol method setListAdapter(ProdutosAdapter)"

Comment: Maybe your layout R.layout.activity_new_user is not using ListView.

Comment: i'll post too. but NewUserActivity dont have ListView.

Comment: Hey Lester , some news ? :D

Comment: Oh I knew it you are using setListAdapter without having a listview inside your layout, and you did not extend your activity to ListActivity. Just google how to use ListView it will return you the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Lester , i think that making a variable public static , and the value be the ItemSelected from spinner , can work , could u help me with this ?

Comment: No. You are not doing the right coding standard if you do that. The problem in your code is the NewUserActivity and your layout. Just focus on that.

Comment: Just google how to use ListView it will return you the answer. Thanks

Comment: Lester , i read about ListView , and so i could understand that is create a list of values populating layout withou need a .xml , right ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you really wanted to use the values of the spinners in Filtro_Activity in DB. It looks like you're almost there.

This line:

```
//chamada para a nova Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(Filtro_Activity.this, ListUsersActivity1.class);
```

should really be:

```
//chamada para a nova Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(Filtro_Activity.this, DB.class);
```

with the DB activity you want to send the data to. Mind you, it probably shouldn't be an activity but a simple class to be instantiated from Filtro_Activity.

"An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user..." A background connection to the DB doesn't really fit and activities typically have GUI which I don't see in DB.

This answer really deviated from the original question, so if you really wanted to send the spinner data, you would run the following code in the second activity onCreate method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String coligada = intent.getStringExtra("coligada");
```

These are from the android tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

By the way, the there are [style guides for Java](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html) which you should probably use.

Comment: could , you make a example ? i dont understand about "EXTRA_MESSAGE" . ;)

Comment: Its the string extra identifier. What you used in the putExtra. Take a look now. Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

For transferring info to another activity use the intent which is used to start the new activity. Below is a sample link http://www.hackpundit.com/android-transfer-data-activity-intent/

Comment: The problem is that i cannot go to second activity without pass the value first