# How could I change background color of a button from a spinner?

Tags: android, colors, spinner

I have to create a spinner that contains some colors and when you select one of them the background color of a button changes. 
This is what I tried:

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">MyFirst</string>


            <string-array name="colors_array">
                <item>red</item>
                <item>green</item>
                <item>blue</item>
                <item>pink</item>
            </string-array>
    </resources>
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.colors_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                bClick.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                bClick.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }

        });
```

Now it makes my button red but I don`t know how to change it to the selected color,how can I get colors value by name(as a string).And here is my colors.xml

```
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="pink">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a switch inside "onItemSelected" method like below:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        bClick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        bClick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        bClick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        bClick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));
                        break;
                    default:
                        bClick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                bClick.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get value of selected item and on basis of value you can set the color of button.Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331854/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-value-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using another array.

```
    <string-array name="colors_array">
        <item>red</item>
        <item>green</item>
        <item>blue</item>
        <item>pink</item>
    </string-array>
<string-array name="colors1_array">
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/green</item>
    <item>@color/blue</item>
    <item>@color/pink</item>
</string-array>
```

And use it like this:

```
 Resources res = getResources();
        final int[] rainbow = this.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors1_array);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                int i = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                bClick.setBackgroundColor(rainbow[i]);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                bClick.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }

        });
```