# get spinner value and post to data base with volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, android-spinner

I'm going to `POST` value of spinners to the database
 unfortunately, I do not know how to implement the `POST` method at any part of the CODE.
I'm having Problem with sending Snipper values.

```
   public class FormActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 

   ....


 spinnerStudy.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String all_study =  spinnerStudy.getItemAtPosition(spinnerStudy.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
        if(!Objects.equals(all_study, "")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),all_study, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        // DO Nothing here
    }
    });
    spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String all_city =  spinnerCity.getItemAtPosition(spinnerCity.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

            if(!Objects.equals(all_city, "")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), all_city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });
        s

    pinnerUniversity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String all_university =  spinnerUniversity.getItemAtPosition(spinnerUniversity.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                if(!Objects.equals(all_university, "")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), all_university, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // DO Nothing here
            }
        });

        spinnerUnited.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String all_united =  spinnerUnited.getItemAtPosition(spinnerUnited.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                if(!Objects.equals(all_united, "")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), all_united, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // DO Nothing here
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
...
```

PLEASE Help ME...In this CASE, the post method HOW sends parameters?
How to get From Spinner a public String? Thank you ALL

Comment: look this for getting data from spinner.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331854/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-value-to-string/38407969
you can post data using volley  like normal way when you achieve data from spinner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //position is spinner position

                    //mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); IS value of position (string)


                    mMap.put("your Key",mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
//the value add to map of volley
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to send multi-value of the spinner at once time.
this means i have a post method of the multi spinner, what is your solution about this?

Comment: Do this code for all spinners. All spinners value will add to your map.