# Can not get inside setOnItemSelectedListener from Spinner

Tags: java, android

Based on information from [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array). I can select room choices from spinner based on ArrayList. However,it never get inside the process setOnItemSelectedListener.I cannot figure out why does it happen.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_room);
SpaceRoomTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tvSpaceRoomTable);
AddroomButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btLinkAddRoom);
Backtomenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBackToMenu_DogTrack);
Delete = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bin);
dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinListRoom);
summitDelete  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDeleteSummit);


AddroomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent LinkToEditroom = new Intent (EditRoom.this,AddRoom.class);
        startActivity(LinkToEditroom);
    }
});

Backtomenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent LinkToHomeMenu = new Intent(EditRoom.this,HomeMenu.class);
        EditRoom.this.startActivity(LinkToHomeMenu);
    }
});


showRoom();


ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,showitemName);
spinnerArrayAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
dropdown.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //   Log.d("TEST","selection is ");
        Object Itemselected =    adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside"+String.valueOf(Itemselected),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});


}
```

Comment: String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spinner selected item value to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331854/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-value-to-string)

Comment: String Itemselected =    dropdown.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

Comment: @Mr.Kim please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In XML Layout :-

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dropdown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then, in your activity `findViewById` like this:-

```
dropdown= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
```

then Create an `ArrayAdapter` using the string array and a default `spinner` layout :-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,showitemName);
spinnerArrayAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
dropdown.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

For `OnIemClickListener` use like this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{ 

Spinner dropdown;
String[] showitemName = {"A","B","C","D","E"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   dropdown= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
   dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,showitemName);
    spinnerArrayAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dropdown.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

}

  //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,long id) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**More information:**

You can check in details from these links:-

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html
https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-onitemselected.html
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/SpinnerItemSelectedListener.htm
https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-get-selected-item-text.html

Comment: Thank you, I will try It !!

Comment: @Mr.Kim okay try it if it will work please accept my answer and give upvote

Comment: Actually, showroom method related to datasnapshot from Firebase so the ArrayList is already be changed all the time. I might have a problem with this. I just guess an assumption.

Comment: @AbhinavI have posted showroom(); Please check it out

Comment: @Abhinavl The Value is came from the Firebase ,so the showitemName will got value from Firebase

Comment: @Mr.Kim have you print this array into logcats?

Comment: @Abhinavl Yes, I check It already. I also  print it by using Toast

Comment: In addition, the list will be used to get Image from Firebase Storage, so the result show that all images from list room be able to retrieve. I have no idea why does it happen

Comment: @Abhinavl I have post onCreate method. Please check it out. By the way, I have try to implement AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener following your answer. Unfortunately, It does not get in the selectItem.

Comment: @Mr.Kim please share your onCreate method in question

Comment: @Abhinavl Ok, I post It in the question

Comment: use findviewbyId again before onItemClick listener

Comment: @Abhinvl  It does not get in OnItemSelectListener as the same. The message in Logcat console said : endAllStagingAnimators on 0x55ac130990 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0x55ac12d5b0

Answer (score 1):

For more Information about showroom method

```
public void showRoom()
{
    refroom.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int Length_Record = dataSnapshot.child("CurrentUser").child("Tracking").child("ListRoom").child("LIST_ROOM_LENGTH").getValue(int.class);
            int RunRecord =0;
            int printRoom =0;
            final String userId = dataSnapshot.child("CurrentUser").child("UserId").getValue(String.class);


            for (DataSnapshot zonesnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("CurrentUser").child("Tracking").child("ListRoom").getChildren())
            {
                if(printRoom!=Length_Record)
                {
                    zonesnapshot.getValue();
                    String[] parts = String.valueOf(zonesnapshot.getValue()).split(",");
                    String part1 = parts[0]; // Room Id
                    String part2 = parts[1]; // Room Name
                    String part3 = parts[2]; // TypeRoom
                    String OnRoom = dataSnapshot.child("CurrentUser").child("Tracking").child("Location").getValue(String.class);

                    itemsName.add(part2+","+part3);  // put to arraylist to prepare a room choice for deletion
                    showitemName.add(part2+"("+part3+")");
                    itemOfUser.put(userId+"Room"+printRoom,part2+","+part3);  // keep room for each user

                    inRow(dataSnapshot.child("CurrentUser").child("UserId").getValue(String.class), RunRecord, part2, OnRoom, part3);

                }
                printRoom++;

            }



            summitDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    storageReference = storage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://********-*****.appspot.com/imagesRoom").child(userId).child(selection);

                    storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Can not delete file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will get the selected item text automatically

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
     //   Log.d("TEST","selection is ");
      String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside"+item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: I have tried this one but the console show message  endAllStagingAnimators on 0x55abf0ca00 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle

Comment: It  never get in onItemSelected. The application show message stopped running