# How access spinner data in button?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

How to access `String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();`  in `button.setOnClickListener()`

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    CountryItem clickedItem = (CountryItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    
                }
            });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Spinner selected item value to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331854/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-value-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

Have the global variable declared as `String clickedCountryName` in your class. In spinner method `onItemSelected` assign the value to this variable, then access the value in the `button.setOnClickListener()`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable outside your spinner listener scope to store the country name

```
    String clickedCountryName = "";
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    CountryItem clickedItem = (CountryItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    
                }
            });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View var1) {
             // access clickedCountryName here
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: bro can write full code of button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your `button.setOnClickListener()`:

```
spinner.getSelectedItem()
```